# Deleting close points from FeatureCollection using buffer in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to generate a number of random points over a given area, e.g. all land masses of the world. For this I have coded

```
var fcLandMasses = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1l9VK5FJ4_hiH2gHjr0MtxwB-CrNEqOE5EBlW6Q');
var fcRandomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(fcLandMasses,numberOfPoints,seed);
```

where you need to set `numberOfPoints` to the number of points you want to generate and `seed` to an arbitrary non-negative integer to ensure repeatability.

How can I clean up the FeatureCollection `fcRandomPoints` such that points located too close to each other (i.e. within a certain buffer) are removed?

I think there are two general choices:

1. Keeping one (e.g. the first-appearing) point of points within that buffer.
2. Keeping the average of all points within that buffer.

I'd like to follow option 2, which will probably include a mapping over `fcRandomPoints`.

What is the most efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 (You can also find it here: https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools):

```
var filterDistance = function(points, distance) {
  var filt2 = ee.List([])
  var filt = points.iterate(function(el, ini){
                         var ini = ee.List(ini)
                         var fcini = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)
                         var buf = ee.Feature(el).geometry().buffer(distance)
                         var s = fcini.filterBounds(buf).size()
                         var cond = s.lte(0)
                         return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, ini.add(el), ini)
                       }, filt2)
  var filtered = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(filt))
  return filtered
}
```

Option 2:

```
var filterDistance = function(points, distance) {      
  var sum = points.iterate(function(el,fir){
    var buf = ee.Feature(el).geometry().buffer(distance)
    var s = points.filterBounds(buf).size()
    return ee.Number(fir).add(s)
  },ee.Number(0))
  var mean = ee.Number(sum).divide(points.size()).ceil()

  var filt2 = ee.List([])
  var filt = points.iterate(function(el, ini){
                         var ini = ee.List(ini)
                         var fcini = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)
                         var buf = ee.Feature(el).geometry().buffer(distance)
                         var s = fcini.filterBounds(buf).size()
                         var cond = s.lte(mean)
                         return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, ini.add(el), ini)
                       }, filt2)
  var filtered = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(filt))
  return filtered
}
```

Test

```
// TEST
var r1 = filterDistance(fcRandomPoints, 50000)
Map.addLayer(r1)
Map.addLayer(fcRandomPoints)
print(r1.size())
```

I think option 1 works better (cleaner), but of course depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Option 1 solved my problem, while Option 2 did not produce correct results on the very same dataset. Great work! Now I need to understand how you did it. ;)

Comment: Yes, option 1 works better, but in option 2 I made what you asked *Keeping the average of all points within that buffer*. I am available as a freelancer ;)

Comment: No, option 2 did not work at all: After running the code, I found many clusters of very close points (definitely within the buffer) were still represented in the reduced dataset. In other words: Option 1 reduced 1000 random points to about 920, which I can confirm to be correct from visual inspection. Option 2 applied on the same dataset reduced the same 1000 random points to 999 reduced points, i.e. basically all points were kept.

Comment: Yes, in option 2 there will be as many close points as the mean in the buffer. You can print the mean (inside the function) and see how many points are 'allowed' within the buffer. When the iteration reaches a point that within its buffer has more than the average (mean), drops that point.

Comment: Ah, I think there was a misunderstanding then. With Option 2 I meant the SPATIAL mean (i.e. the mean location) of the points within the buffer should be kept, all original points within the buffer should be deleted. The number of points in the reduced dataset would then be exactly the same as if Option 1 were applied. Only difference: Location of the reduced points.