# Spatial thinning Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-join

I am trying to spatially thin occurrence data for use in a Species Distribution Model. Because my data represent "presence-only" or "citizen science" data, I am trying to account for the effects of sampling bias by subsampling the points so that no two points fall within X distance of each other. This is the **Systematic sampling** approach detailed in [Fourcade etal. 2014](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0097122) and many other recent Species Distribution models.

So far, I have tried variations on this theme:

Create spatial buffer around each occurrence point:

```
var hydrilla = users/me/myoccurrencecsv.csv
var hyd_buffered = hydrilla.map(function(feat){
  return feat.buffer(5000)
})

//Join data so that no two points fall within 5 km

var distFilter =  ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo', 
  rightField: '.geo', 
  maxError: 100
});

var join = ee.Join.inner()
var hydrilla_corrected = join.apply(hydrilla,hyd_buffered,distFilter)
```

I am still fairly unfamiliar with the ee.Join process, so I'm sure something I am doing is wrong, but I have tried an `ee.Join.inverted()` as well as an `ee.Join.simple()` but nothing seems to give me what I want. I have done an extensive googling of this problem in EE and have not found any satisfactory results.

**Edit:** Here is another pseudo solution that I propose

```
var hyd_corrected = hydrilla.map(function(feat){
//Buffer around each feature
  var buffered = feat.buffer(5000)

//Cast each buffer object to a geometry object by referencing the geometry properties of the feature 
// and receiving the coordinates
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon(ee.List(buffered.geometry().coordinates()));

//Return Null if the feature intersects the geometry
  return ee.Algorithms.If(feat.intersects(geom),null,feat)
})
```

This doesn't work because each feature obviously intersects its own buffered geometry, but what is relevant is *adjacent* features.

Here is the link to my script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/190c7ec503bd9aff08099c7b500ad8a6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has a solution:

[Deleting close points from FeatureCollection using buffer in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258866/deleting-close-points-from-featurecollection-using-buffer-in-google-earth-engine)

```
var filterDistance = function(points, distance) {
  var filt2 = ee.List([])
  var filt = points.iterate(function(el, ini){
                         var ini = ee.List(ini)
                         var fcini = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)
                         var buf = ee.Feature(el).geometry().buffer(distance)
                         var s = fcini.filterBounds(buf).size()
                         var cond = s.lte(0)
                         return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, ini.add(el), ini)
                       }, filt2)
  var filtered = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(filt))
  return filtered
}
var filtered = filterDistance(**MYFEATURECOLLECTION**, 50000)
Map.addLayer(filtered)
```